# Setup file-system based routing in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing

I'm really a fan of the simplicity PHP offers in serving pages, everything is based on the filesystem. I want to do the same thing with Node. I tried one routing setup that worked like this for views, but broke my public folder:

```
//using express:
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  file = req.params[0].substr(1, req.params[0].length);
  console.log('requesting: ' + file);
  res.render(file, {locals: {
    req: req,
    params: req.query
  }});
});
```

*So...*

#### What's the best way to setup filesystem based/php style routing in Node?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen Express framework, but I rewrote the old MVC framework (with routing) for version 3: https://github.com/tehlulz/express-MVC/tree/javascript might be of some help :)

Comment: This should work if you `use` your routes after static -- if static can't find the file, it will pass along the request to the next middleware.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I build exactly what you are looking for. I use this to serve up `.jade` files, obviously you can tweak this for your use case.

```
var url = require('url');
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var fs = require('fs');

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

/**
 * Generic "get" attempts to route to known JADE files.
 * If no known JADE files, then we pass routing to next() (should be static).
 */
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname.toLowerCase(); // make matching case insenstive

  // First case: with no path name, render the default index.jade
  if(!pathname) {
    res.render('index', {});
  }
  // Second case: path ending in '/' points to a folder, use index.jade from that folder
  else if (pathname === '/' || pathname.charAt(pathname.length-1) === '/' ){
    res.render(__dirname + '/views' + pathname + 'index.jade', {});
  }
  // Third case: looks like an actual file, attempt to render
  else {
    // Attempt to find the referenced jade file and render that. Note 'views' is default path.
    fs.stat( (__dirname + "/views" + pathname + '.jade'), function(err, stats){
      // There was an error, the file does not exist pass control to the static handler
      if(err || !stats) {
        next();
      }
      // We found the file, render it.
      else{
        res.render(pathname.substring(1), {});
      }
    });

  }
});

app.listen(port);
```

Note, there should be more `app.use()` statements there for handling cookies, parsing the body etc. Also, the second param of the `render` is always empty. You may want to fill this out with things like `{layout: xyz}` or generic variables that need to come in to the rendered pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use express.static()

For examples:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.use('/uploads', express.static(PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FOLDER));
});
```

Comment: I'm already using static as per the express generated template app.